# Laravel 5.4 TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68 on some device

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I know it's one of the most asked question around here, but I really read everything on the first 10 pages results on google and nothing solved my problem.

On a **fresh installation** of laravel 5.4 , generated the auth controller, views, etc. via *php artisan make:auth* when I try to register (or login) in **some device** I get the following error:

***TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68***

I'm running this application in local on debian 8.7 and php7 (could it be related to the problem in some way ?)
From my pc, iphone 7, another windows 10 desktop it works perfectly, but on a Huawei p8 lite, ipad 2 and lubuntu (quite old version) I get that error. So it's really weird because it just happends with some device (no matter whaht O.S. no matter what browser).

I can already tell you that I tried grant permissions to sessions folder, change session_domain, clearing cache (but as I said I'm trying this on a fresh installation), change {{ csrf_token }} to {!! csrf_token !!} , etc.

Just to give you more information about my system, this is the php version i'm using:

```
php --version
PHP 7.0.17-1~dotdeb+8.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.17-1~dotdeb+8.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend 
Technologies
```

I'm really stuck on this for days. Got no more ideas.

Comment: I think you have changed cookie domain from your session.php config file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you added $this->middleware('auth'); inside the constructor of your controller to get the authentication working. Add the following at the top as well, under your login/register forms, if you are using {!! Form::someElement !!}:

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Or if you are using input tags inside your forms, just add this just after the `<form>` tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: I created the controllers and views via artisan command (php artisan make:auth ) so everything has been generated automatically. More consider that it works fine in some device as I said. it just happends on some device.

Comment: I'm running this application in local on debian 8.7 and php7 (could it be related to the problem in some way ?) From my pc, iphone 7, another windows 10 desktop it works perfectly, but on a Huawei p8 lite, ipad 2 and lubuntu (quite old version) I get that error. So it's really weird because it just happends with some device (no matter whaht O.S. no matter what browser). I wrote it in the question. It doesn't work also from a pc with linux...so really I'm groping in the dark

Comment: ok got. it in linux you want to change the folder permisions and also run it with php artisan serve

Comment: I already did it (set to 777) and nothing changed. same problem. Consider that i'm running it on debian linux and it works fine, from another pc it doesn't (i'm connecting through the ip:8000 because i'm running it from local debian)

Comment: why should i follow the tutorial of laravel 5.0 when I already installed laravel 5.4 and everything works fine..

Comment: You just install laravel step by step using this doc using command line.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but maybe I didn't explain the problem very well. I use laravel in several projects and I never had this problem before. I don't need to install it from zero again, and I just installed the new project from command line (i.e laravel new test) then created the auth controllers and views with laravel make:auth and it works fine on my pc and on other devices. I'm just getting this error on some device. I don't think it's related to the laravel installation imho

Answer (score 0):

in your **.env** file add

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did these steps.

1. `php artisan cache:clear //cache clear`
2. `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
   //place inside the form tags`